# Javascript Functions in React: why isn't my function returning multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, for-loop

I want to return a 'hi' div, for each item and key pair inside a given object. So when I have 2 pairs in the object, I want to return 2 divs. However, I only ever get 1 div returned. Why is this happening? Am I missing something really obvious, that I'm just not getting right now? How can I return more than 1 div?

Here is the function:

```
createList() {
        for(let chosenBook in this.props.updateBasket.productMap) {
            return <div>hi</div>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for loop` will exit if it encounters the `return` statement. What you need is to `map` over the `object keys` and return the result.

```
createList() {
        return Object.keys(this.props.updateBasket.productMap).map(key => {
            return <div>hi</div>
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(let chosenBook in this.props.updateBasket.productMap) {  //wrong syntax
                    return <div>hi</div>
      }
```

use `of`, not `in`

```
  for(let chosenBook of this.props.updateBasket.productMap) {  //correct syntax
                return <div>hi</div>
  }
```

Comment: I'm using an object; that's why I'm using for...in instead of for...of :)